# How to restrict access to API to the portal run on browser through Nginx

Tags: nginx

**Scenario**

I have a system with an api server and a front end (static website run on browsers) and they are publicly available under 2 domain names a.example.com and a-api.example.com

**Question**

How do I restrict access to my api at a-api.example.com to my front end only (e.g. no one can arbitrarily `curl` to it and be able to access)? Or is it possible at all?

If you can add a sample nginx block that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot block curl calls completely.

However, you can make them more difficult by requiring that HTTP referrer header is set to the api. You can use [nginx HTTP referer module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html) for this. An example configuration:

```
server {
    valid_referers a-api.example.com;

    if ($invalid_referer) {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

This is not adding any security to your website. It is trivial for bad actor to add the required HTTP header when making requests to `a-api.example.com`.

Therefore it is important that best security prcatices are used in your API implementation.